# symfony2 behat selenium login

Tags: symfony, selenium, authentication

I am testing my symfony2 login with behat and with selenium driver, but it does not work properly. I think the symfony2 session is not shared between the selenium session, which is bad because I have no SecurityPasswordToken in my selenium session :(

I have to test some javascript on a page which is protected through a secured firewall in symfony2.

Login works perfectly with default driver in my test feature, but when I force this feature to run it with selenium (with "@javascript") it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

When using any driver except `symfony2`, the kernel used by the app and the kernel used by Mink are separate.

You don't need to have access to the security context to test if logging in works. Just login via the UI and test the stuff you need.